# How to know cause of unzip returning code 81

Tags: zip, yocto, unzip, bitbake

I am compiling a linux-based system using yocto. one of the steps of the compilation (using bitbake) fails while unpacking a ZIP file. The command that is failing is the following:

```
unzip -q -o '/absolute/path/to/file.zip'
```

Which return `failed with return value 81`

I have checked the meaning of unzip's code 81 which means: *testing or extraction of one or more files failed due to unsupported compression methods or unsupported decryption.*

The same unzip command works when run from a terminal.

**Is there a way yo check the cause of the error 81?** In other words, which is the unsupported compression method or unsupported decryption?

More information:

- I have run `unzip -v file.zip` and found that compression method is
  **BZip2** which should be supported.
- The file is not encrypted.
- The file is not password protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yocto unzip is not built with bzip2 support. Assuming that the file can be opened with bzip2 tool (and as pmqs comments this may be an incorrect assumption), I *think* it should just start working if you rename the file so that the format is recognised and the correct tool gets used. Something like this:

```
SRC_URI = "http://example.com/download/fname-${PV}.zip;downloadfilename=fname-${PV}.bz2"
```

Comment: I don't think that changing the filename extension from `zip` to `bz2` will be enough to allow `bzip2` to uncompress it.

Comment: You may be correct: the bzip2 support in unzip is not really documented anywhere that I can find

Comment: It is correct that bzip2 was not supported. I recompressed the .zip file into a tar.bz2 and now it work. It still confuses me the fact that unzip actually works on a bash terminal but not on a yocto compilation.

Comment: That's because in the terminal you are using unzip from your host distro. Yocto typically uses tools that it builds itself, and not the tools from a build host

Answer (score 0):

Use [Zip-Ada](https://github.com/zertovitch/zip-ada). It supports Deflate, Deflate64, **BZip2** and LZMA for decompression.